# Auto height removing float

Tags: html, css, css-float

I've made some code where the "section" that automatically determines the height when the content is inside, however, I want to have multiple columns in the same row and the columns are currently stacking.

How would I set the columns on to the same row without using float element as it takes the auto height of the section away?

```css
.section {
    width:100%;
    padding-top: 60px;
    padding-right: 0px;
    padding-bottom: 62px;
    padding-left: 0px;
    background-color: #f5f5f5;
    position: relative;
}

.row {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 1080px;
    margin: auto;
    padding: 33px 0;
}

.column{
    width: 100%;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 9;
}

.container {
    overflow: hidden !important;
    position: relative;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    background-color: transparent;
    width: 300px;
    height: 500px;
    border-radius: 0px;
}
```

```html
 <div class="section">
  <div class="row">
   <div class="column">
    <div class="container">
     <img src="img.png">
     <div class="content_block">
                        <div class="text">
      <h2>Title</h2>
                        <a>2 reports</a>
                        </div>
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>
            <div class="column">
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way would be to use flexbox.

So just add ..

```
display: flex;
```

.. and you could probably remove the width (or set it to 50%)

```
.row {
    display: flex;
    position: relative;
    width: 50%;
    max-width: 1080px;
    margin: auto;
    padding: 33px 0;
}
```

There are other ways of course (colspan, inline-block) but flexbox will give you even-height columns and make any other formatting much easier.